What's the role of "would" in this sentence?
Can you explain how "would" works when speaker B answers A's question?
A: Should "the" be capitalized when it is part of a title and the title cannot go without the definite article?
The specific example is "the Green Airport" (name of a project that deals with building environment-friendly airports).
B: Well, as a title, the first word is always capitalised. So it would be The Green Airport.

See https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/355099/138287 btw; "the" may or may not be part of the title.

"How much oil should I put in?  -- The recipe calls for a 2-to-1 ratio, so it would be a full cup."  There is an implicit condition: "if you are following the recipe, given how much of the other ingredient you've used."  In your case, "If you are following the rule that the first word of a title is always capitalised, your title would be ..."

It would be The Green Airport = It will amount to The Green Airport.
